# Actions on Google V2 idToken not sent

Tags: actions-on-google

Looking at the docs for the appRequest for actions on google https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppRequest

The user object says that the `userId` property is now deprecated and that we should use the `idToken` instead https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppRequest#user

However testing out a V2 action in the simulator, my response only includes a `userId` property and not the `idToken`

I'm definitely using V2 of the API and this doesn't say it's an optional field when linking accounts (for what it's worth I **haven't** done any account linking).

Should this field be included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not *quite* what that page says.

Yes, it says the `userId` property is deprecated - it does not show any replacement there. It was deprecated without a direct replacement, although you can [create one yourself if needed](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info#migration_guide).

It does **not** say the `idToken` replaces it, although you can get a unique ID from the `idToken`, it doesn't do so directly. It also doesn't give you the `idToken` unless you [take some steps to enable it](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in).

To use the `idToken` to get a user identifier, you need to do a few things:

1. Turn on Google Sign In for Assistant.
2. Request the user sign into your Action using Google Sign In for Assistant *or* have them sign via other means (Google Sign In for the web or for mobile) to the same project.
3. When you get the `idToken`, verify and extract the JWT payload. If you're using the action-on-google library, it will do this for you. If not, this is a standard JWT token which you should verify and the payload includes the ID.

Comment: Thank you, you're right in I did make some assumptions about the userId being replaced by the idToken - though I did try to clarify this by asking if the field should be included. I think the confusion stemmed from the fact that it doesn't actually state idToken is an optional field whereas the `accessToken` field does say it's "only available if account linking is defined". Thanks again